# Executing a assembly shellcode on Linux (Fedora) hello.S with 's-proc -e' returns SIGSEGV

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, shellcode

I have written a simple Linux assembly shellcode which print "Hello, world!" to stdout.

```
xor eax,eax  
xor ebx,ebx  
xor ecx,ecx  
xor edx,edx  
jmp short   string  
code:  
pop ecx  
mov bl,1  
mov al,13  
mov al,4  
int 0x80  
dec bl  
mov al,1  
int 0x80  
string:  
call    code  
db  'hellow, world!'
```

The program name is `hello.S`. Now, compiling the code:

```
$ nasm -o hello hello.S

$ ./s-proc -p hello

/* The following shellcode is 47 bytes long: */
char shellcode[] =
    "\x66\x31\xc0\x66\x31\xdb\x66\x31\xc9\x66\x31\xd2\xeb\x10\x66"
    "\x59\xb3\x01\xb0\x0d\xb0\x04\xcd\x80\xfe\xcb\xb0\x01\xcd\x80"
    "\xe8\xed\xff\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x77\x2c\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c"
    "\x64\x21";


$ ./s-proc -e hello

Calling code ...

Segmentation fault

$
```

The program is correct but it gives error.

About the s-proc:

s-proc is a C program which used to execute the shellcode. Using ld command makes shellcode large therefor I used s-proc.

The source code of s-pros.c could be found [here](http://kodu.ut.ee/~mroos/secprog/2010/shellcode/s-proc.c) and [here](http://www.safemode.org/files/zillion/shellcode/doc/Writing_shellcode.html)

Comment: *The program is correct but it gives error.* One of these statements is **false**.

Answer (score 2):

The wrapper code simply uses `malloc` to get a chunk of memory and reads the file into it. However nowadays heap memory is not executable, hence you get a segfault. You could use `mprotect` to mark the required page(s) executable. If you decide to put the shellcode on the stack, you need executable stack turned on (`-z execstack` option to `gcc`).